# Should I use DataInputStream or BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, io

I want to read each line from a text file and store them in an ArrayList (each line being one entry in the ArrayList).

So far I understand that a BufferedInputStream writes to the buffer and only does another read once the buffer is empty which minimises or at least reduces the amount of operating system operations.

Am I correct - do I make sense?

If the above is the case in what situations would anyone want to use DataInputStream. And finally which of the two should I be using and why - or does it not matter.

Comment: What makes you think they are interchangeable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a normal `InputStream` (e.g. `FileInputStream`) wrapped in an `InputStreamReader` and then wrapped in a `BufferedReader` - then call `readLine` on the `BufferedReader`.

`DataInputStream` is good for reading primitives, length-prefixed strings etc.

Comment: why can't I just use something like FileReader as a Reader?

Comment: @engine: If you only need things from `Reader`, you can - but that doesn't have `readLine`, and this question was about reading *lines*.

Answer (score 8):

The two classes are not mutually exclusive - you can use both of them if your needs suit.

As you picked up, BufferedInputStream is about reading in blocks of data rather than a single byte at a time. It also provides the convenience method of readLine(). However, it's also used for peeking at data further in the stream then rolling back to a previous part of the stream if required (see the mark() and reset() methods).

DataInputStream/DataOutputStream provides convenience methods for reading/writing certain data types. For example, it has a method to write/read a UTF String. If you were to do this yourself, you'd have to decide on how to determine the end of the String (i.e. with a terminator byte or by specifying the length of the string).

This is different from BufferedInputStream's readLine() which, as the method sounds like, only returns a single line. writeUTF()/readUTF() deal with Strings - that string can have as many lines it it as it wants.

BufferedInputStream is suitable for most text processing purposes. If you're doing something special like trying to serialize the fields of a class to a file, you'd want to use DataInput/OutputStream as it offers greater control of the data at a binary level.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You are confusing a BufferedInputStream with a BufferedReader. InputStreams have no concept of a line so do not have readLine()

Answer (score 5):

You can always use both:

```
final InputStream inputStream = ...;
final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream =
        new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
final DataInputStream dataInputStream =
        new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
```

Comment: can you explain this a little in detail ? why to use them both like this ?

Comment: `DataInputStream` does not buffer input, `BufferedInputStream` does (obviously). By wrapping `InputStream` with `BufferedInputStream`, then wrapping `BufferedInputStream` with `DataInputStream`, you get an input stream that is easier to work with (the convenience methods `DataInputStream` provides are useful) and backed by a buffered reader, making I/O more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

**InputStream:** Base class to read byte from stream (network or file ), provide ability to read byte from the stream and delete the end of the stream.

**DataInputStream:** To read data directly as a primitive datatype.

**BufferInputStream:** Read data from the input stream and use buffer to optimize the speed to access the data.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud use DataInputStream in cases when you need to interpret the primitive types in a  file written by a language other Java in platform-independent manner.

Answer (score 2):

I would advocate using [Jakarta Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and the [readlines()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.2/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.InputStream%29) method (of whatever variety).

It'll look after buffering/closing etc. and give you back a list of text lines. I'll happily roll my own input stream wrapping with buffering etc., but nine times out of ten the Commons IO stuff works fine and is sufficient/more concise/less error prone etc.

Answer (score 0):

The differences are:

- The **DataInputStream** works with the binary data, while the **BufferedReader** work with character data.
- All primitive data types can be handled by using the corresponding methods in **DataInputStream** class, while only string data can be read from **BufferedReader** class and they need to be parsed into the respective primitives.
- **DataInputStream** is a part of filtered streams, while **BufferedReader** is not.
- **DataInputStream** consumes less amount of memory space being it is a binary stream, whereas **BufferedReader** consumes more memory space being it is character stream.
- The data to be handled is limited in **DataInputStream**, whereas the number of characters to be handled has wide scope in **BufferedReader**.