# Java DataInputStream read operations throwing Exceptions

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to familiarize myself with Java IO classes, so I wrote the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileIO.txt");
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

    //fos.write(9999);
    //bos.write(9999);
    dos.writeInt(9999);
    dos.writeBytes("中文字(Chinese)\n");
    dos.writeChars("中文字(Chinese)\n");
    dos.flush();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("fileIO.txt");
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

    System.out.println(dis.readInt());
    System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this:

```
9999
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:592)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:547)
at IO.main(IO.java:34)
```

Could anyone point out why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform a readUTF, the first two byte are used for the length. This means if you have random bytes there (not from writeUTF) you will attempt to read very long string instead and as there is not enough data, you will get EOFException.

Comment: I see! I suppose this also explains the suspicious blank space `' '` in between every English letter when using writeChar. ex: ( C h i n e s e )

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
dos.writeBytes("中文字(Chinese)\n");
dos.writeChars("中文字(Chinese)\n");
```

you need

```
dos.writeUTF("中文字(Chinese)\n");
```

Comment: I see, so you can throw in a lot of bytes and character with writeBytes & writeChars but only read one at a time with their repective read operations?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737318/should-i-use-datainputstream-or-bufferedinputstream) will be helpful. The exception is thrown (from [oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF%28%29)) -

> if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.

Comment: +1 for the diagram at the top. I find it to be of much greater importance. I wonder why they didn't copy & paste it to DataOutputStream, which I read, and missed out writeUTF.

Comment: @SomeNoobStudent Because `DataOutputStream()` doesn't throw `EOFExceptions`?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use `readUTF()` to read items that were written with `writeUTF()`.

This is true in general for `readXXX()` and `writeXXX()` for any XXX (unless you want to read the bytes of an int or some such and you know what you're doing).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't UTF char after Integer number in your file. When you're trying read UTF there is End of File so you have the exception.

Try in debug mode stop before you read and check manually to your file, what do you have then?