# Bluetooth on Android not sending messages

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, message, bluecove

I have followed [Google's tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAServer) on using Bluetooth on Android. On the server side which is a computer I've used Bluecove.

I have managed to establish the connection between the devices (they weren't paired first and when I ran the program both of the devices asked to accept the pairing). Now I have problem with sending data over the connection. In the [Managing a connection section](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) there's a method called `write`. With that function I'm not able to send anything. It doesn't fail (no errors) but the message doesn't reach the server.

On the server after accepting the connection (acceptAndConnect()) I have the following

```
DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(connection.openInputStream());

while(true) {
    String input = "";
    char c;

    while(((c = inputStream.readChar()) > 0) && (c != '\n')) {
        input += c;
    }

    System.out.println("Received: " + input);
}
```

It doesn't print anything.

The code on the client side is exactly the same as in the tutorial. Where is the problem?

Edit. Actually, if I print `c` in the server code shown up I get something strange. I've tried to send `hello\n`. When printing `c`, I get `桥
汬
漊`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of more googleing I found [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737318/should-i-use-datainputstream-or-bufferedinputstream/737329#737329) and changed the `DataInputStream` to an InputStream wrapped in an `InputStreamReader`  and that one in a `BufferedReader`. Then I can use `readLine()` and I get the characters right.