# Client-Server Program - Basic Differences and questions

Tags: java

I have 2 programms in Java (1 client and 1 Server) with the following code

My questions is, why the use of the buffered reader is used? what is his purpose on the below program? For simplify reasons, couldnt work only with datainputstream/dataoutputstream on both client and server? they will still exchange messages right ?

Sorry, but i am a newbie on coding :P

Code below:

#### Server

```
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*;  
class MyServerPing{  
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
    System.out.println("PING SERVER");
    ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(3333);  
    Socket s=ss.accept();  

    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

    String str="",str2="";  
    while(!str.equals("stop")){  
        str=din.readUTF();  
        System.out.println("client says: "+str);  
        str2=br.readLine();  
        dout.writeUTF(str2);  
        dout.flush();  
    }  
    din.close();  
    s.close();  
    ss.close();  
    }
}
```

#### Client

```
import java.net.*;  
import java.io.*;  
class MyClientPong{  
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{  
    Socket s=new Socket("localhost",3333);  
    DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());  
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());  
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  

    String str="",str2="";  
    while(!str.equals("stop")){  
        str=br.readLine();  
        dout.writeUTF(str);  
        dout.flush();  
        str2=din.readUTF();  
        System.out.println("Server says: "+str2);  
    }  

    dout.close();  
    s.close();  
    }
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: DataInputStream works with Binary data, BufferedReader works with character data.
Please see more differences between Input/Output Streams and Buffered Readers/Writers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63423198/8148637

Comment: ok thank you , but based on the above code, can someone explain why the use of both methods? what good did he get etc? thanks